# RubyMine Rails console create error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine, ruby-1.9.3

I'm currently working on a Ruby on Rails application using RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1. I'm using Rails 4 and Ruby 1.9.3p429. In my application, I have a class file 'user.rb' with the following code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness:{case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6}

  has_secure_password
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
end
```

and a related migration file '[timestamp]_create_users.rb' with the following:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Using the RubyMines Run Rake Task, I ran a db:migration to create the users table. The problem is that RubyMines doesn't accept any User.create command to enter data into the database. E.g

```
User.create (first_name:"John",last_name:"Doe",email:"jdoe@example.com",password:"testing",password_confirmation:"testing")
```

The error it gives is

```
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
User.create (first_name:"John",last_name:"Doe",ema...
                        ^
(irb):1: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end
...er.create (first_name:"John",last_name:"Doe",email:"jdoe@...
                                ^
```

This works fine when I run it in my command prompt using the 'rails console', but it gets tedious to repeatedly refer to the command prompt. I've tried running the Rails Console in RubyMine in both default and development, with neither yielding a positive result. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to resolve this?

Comment: Hello, not sure but try to remove the space between User.create and the left parenthesis User.create(...) instead of User.create (...)

Comment: It worked! Thank you! The odd thing is that it worked with the space between User.create and (..) in the command prompt.

Comment: glad if it works for you. have swing... Remember to mark your question as answered ^_^

Comment: Can you post the answer? I can't mark it as answered unless there's an actual answer and I'm new so I can't answer my own question as of yet.

Comment: I've just done it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the space between User.create and the left parenthesis User.create(...) instead of User.create (...)

Cheers